# How to do optimization with sql server exists clause?

Tags: sql-server, optimization, inner-join, exists

I have a sql query which contains the exists clause. Previously there was Inner Join between two tables but due to some new condition I replaces Inner Join with exists clause. Below is my query -

```
SELECT id, 
       Count(id) AS 'ItemCount' 
FROM   table1 t1 
WHERE  ( EXISTS(SELECT DISTINCT messageid 
                FROM   table2 t2 
                WHERE  t2.messageid = t1.chatmessageid 
                       AND t2.receiverid = 'xyzo-1234' 
                       AND t2.groupid = 'wxfx-1234' 
                       AND ( t1.userid = 'ttew-3457' 
                              OR t1.userid IS NULL )) 
          OR ( t1.userid = 'ttew-3457' ) ) 
       AND ( t1.machineid != 'C34F-A609' ) 
       AND ( t1.createdtime > '2016-07-20 :: 07:21:51.9118534' ) 
       AND ( t1.createdtime <= '2016-07-27 :: 13:25:30.1016155' ) 
       AND ( t1.groupid = 'wxfx-1234' ) 
GROUP  BY t1.id 
ORDER  BY t1.id
```

But this query is taking little bit more time than the previous query and I want to optimize it more. Can anyone suggest me how I can more optimize this query ?

Comment: Well, for starters `DISTINCT` is pointless within an `EXISTS` since all it cares about is the distinction between 0 rows and more than 0 rows.

Comment: `EXISTS(...OR t1.UserId IS NULL` - are you sure?

Comment: if you have columns which can have NULL value, rewrite with something like that `isnull(t1.UserId, '')`

Comment: I would suggest you start using the `DATETIME2` data type to store date + time information. That'll make comparisons/lookup a lot faster.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT Id, COUNT(Id) as 'ItemCount' 
FROM table1 t1 WHERE (
                    EXISTS( 
                            ***SELECT Count 1 0 FROM table2 t2***  
                            WHERE t2.MessageId = t1.ChatMessageId AND t2.ReceiverId ='xyzo-1234' 
                            AND t2.GroupId='wxfx-1234'  
                            AND (t1.UserId ='ttew-3457' OR t1.UserId IS NULL) 
                            ) 
                OR (t1.UserId ='ttew-3457')
            ) 
        AND  (t1.MachineId != 'C34F-A609') AND (t1.CreatedTime > '2016-07-20 :: 07:21:51.9118534')
        AND (t1.CreatedTime <= '2016-07-27 :: 13:25:30.1016155') AND (t1.GroupId='wxfx-1234') 
GROUP BY t1.Id  
ORDER BY t1.Id
```